# Is it possible to connect to TOR without having it installed?

Tags: c, tcp, rust, tor

How do i connect to Tor via TCP in C or Rust, without having the Tor browser installed, in my windows pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the Txtorcon and Stem libraries require a Tor binary already installed though. It is possible to use the Tor included with the Tor Browser Bundle, connecting on port 9150 (with control port of 9151).

Better yet though, you can download the ["Expert Bundle"](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) to get the Tor binary without any browser.The expert bundle connects to the Tor network and allows you to make SOCKS5 connections and control port connections. You can control everything it does via the config file or in real time through a 'Tor controller' on the control port.
You can download it from [Download](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) | [Mirror 1](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Tor.shtml)